# MS Access Union Data Type Mismatch when importing to Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access

So I built a tool to import data from an Access database into Excel, pretty simple. However, because of the project I had to create multiple queries and a union in order to get the correct output. Now when I go to import the data into Excel using that Union I get a data mismatch error.

I checked all the data types and they all match. I even ran the script using one of the queries in the Union and I am able to import the data that way, but it only gives me half of what I need.

When you create a union between 2 queries, does it alter the data types in any way? Possibly moving from Number to Text?

Thank you!

Comment: The data types of the first union statement take precedent over all the other unions.  So if you have date field in the first one which is a text in the 2nd, the system will try to implicitly cast the text to a date and possibly fail, giving you `data type mismatch error`.  So all the datatypes in the Unioned queries MUST be the same as the data types defined in the first SQL statement.  You said you checked, but there MUST be a variance!  I'd add 1 union at a time until you find the query which is causing the issue.  Run the union results to a make table to force the error.

Comment: Alternatively, run a make table off each separate query and compare the data type results of each table made.  One (or more) of them will be different!

Comment: I don't seem to get an error when running the union in Access. The error comes up when I try to use the union to pull data out of the access db into excel. Sorry, I'm still new at this so it's confusing me even to try and explain the error I am getting. Thank you!

Comment: "I don't seem to get an error when running the union in Access." ***Even as a make table?***  You can run a query and start getting results back and displayed, but until you "Scroll" to the record that's causing the problem, Access will not indicate there's an error!  (so if you run the query SCROLL to the bottom (last record)  By making a table you force the engine to generate the dataset which forces it to evaluate the record potentially causing the error.

Comment: When running the import into excel, you're forcing the engine to evaluate all the records, when it gets to one or more records it's unable to implicitly cast some data to the desired type, as a result the error is occurring.  by running a make table on the whole set, you'd be able to get the error in MSAccess.  By Running a make table on each union-ed statement you'll be able to compare the derived datatypes of each union, thus aid you in isolating the issue.